# Confusing sentence structure

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

> What does pre-med need with history?

The sentence in question is referring to a pre-med student. Isn't that sentence confusing? I mean, I get the meaning. But isn't there a better way to structure it?

> Something like:
>
> > 1. Why does a pre-med need history?
> > 2. What does a pre-med do with history?

Ps. I got the sentence from a dialogue from the movie *A Man From Earth*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a colloquialism.

"What do you need with X?" means "What need do you have for X?"

Comment: Hmmm... So this sentence means basically `What need does a pre-med have for history`?

Comment: Yes, that is what the sentence means. You original sentence lacks an article, BTW.  "What does **a** pre-med need with history?"

Comment: Compare: https://books.google.com/books?id=RId8W04f6MEC&pg=PT137&dq=%22what+do+you+need+with%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilwc75zKLXAhVEQCYKHSRZBOwQ6AEIYTAK#v=onepage&q=%22what%20do%20you%20need%20with%22&f=false